# How queue channel order works if capacity is full and new messages are coming?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a queue with unbounded capacity. I can limit the capacity however, my question is in what order messages will be processed. If queue has say 100,000 message and new message are still coming.
will output channel get the new message coming or will pick it from queue in FIFO order?

```
<channel id="DeliveryProcessChannel">
 <queue/>
</channel>

<aggregator input-channel="DeliveryProcessChannel" output- 
   channel="EmailDispatchChannel"
   discard-channel="EmailDispatchChannel"
   expire-groups-upon-completion="true"    
   send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
   group-timeout="1000"
   correlation-strategy-expression="T(Thread).currentThread().id"
   release-strategy-expression="size() == 1000">
       <poller max-messages-per-poll="1000" fixed-rate="1000"/>
</aggregator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueueChannel` is fully based on FIFO algorithm.
To be precise: an in-memory (default) one is fully based on the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

All the persistent implementations are based on a store FIFO semantics. For example JDBC one has this query:

```
@Override
public String getPollFromGroupQuery() {
    return "SELECT %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID, %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_BYTES from %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE " +
            "where %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.GROUP_KEY = :group_key and %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.REGION = :region " +
            "order by CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY";
}
```

If capacity is full, this logic is performed:

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element into this queue, waiting up to the
 * specified wait time if necessary for space to become available.
 *
 * @param e the element to add
 * @param timeout how long to wait before giving up, in units of
 *        {@code unit}
 * @param unit a {@code TimeUnit} determining how to interpret the
 *        {@code timeout} parameter
 * @return {@code true} if successful, or {@code false} if
 *         the specified waiting time elapses before space is available
 * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted while waiting
 * @throws ClassCastException if the class of the specified element
 *         prevents it from being added to this queue
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if some property of the specified
 *         element prevents it from being added to this queue
 */
boolean offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

which is called from the `QueueChannel.send()` returning a `boolean` to indicate if message has need offered for queue or not.

If you would like to change the order message in a queue channel processed, you can provide your own `Queue` impl:

```
/**
 * Create a channel with the specified queue.
 *
 * @param queue The queue.
 */
public QueueChannel(Queue<Message<?>> queue) {
```

There is also a `PriorityChannel` in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-prioritychannel

Comment: Thanks Artem! also, my poller does not have executor. Is it a good practice to have executor or it is okay to live with default 10 task-scheduler threads?

Comment: Well, if you introduce an executor, you will lose a FIFO order for messages pulled from the queue. So, everything depends on your requirements

Comment: Did not get you Artem, How executor will lose the order(FIFO), executor is just for controlling threads on poller which has default 10 threads anyways. Order should be controlled by queue. Did you mean parallelly running thread will cause the loss of order, if so that would be trivial as long as queue to popping messaging in FIFO order.

Comment: Yes, queue is still polling in the proper order. That's not a question. But your processing with that executor may lead to a parallelism. Therefore I think we can treat it as a lose of FIFO: with an executor it is already no matter how we pull messages from a queue if we process them in the separate threads.